# count total in ES

Tags: python, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

If I have below data in ES and dynamoDB. How can I count total books_borrowed using query?

### user

user_id: 1,
name: "ABC",
books_borrwoed: 5,
unit_price: 10

user_id: 2,
name: "dead",
books_borrwoed: 5,
unit_price: 10

I cant use loop, as there can be more than 10k records in a month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html), to get the sum of `books_borrwed` field

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "total_books": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "books_borrwoed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search result will be :

```
"aggregations": {
    "total_books": {
      "value": 10.0
    }
  }
```

**Update 1:**

If you need to multiply price of each book by 5, you can use script with sum aggregation

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "total_books": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "doc['books_borrwoed'].value * 5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "total_books": {
      "value": 50.0
    }
  }
```

And if you want to take the value from your data, you can use below query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "total_books": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "doc['books_borrwoed'].value * doc['unit_price'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I need to multipy books_borrwoed: 5 with unit price before addition?